# How to remove a class that is no longer used when using SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am working on a `Java` project in `Eclipse` and I use `SVN` to commit various versions of it in the repository. However I have noticed, that when I delete a class and I then commit the project, the old class is still included in the latest committed version of the project. Is there any way to prevent the `SVN` from maintaining classes which have been actually deleted?

**Update:** The same problem comes out when I rename a class and then I try to commit the new version of the project. It keeps both classes and stores both on the repository version. How can I prevent it from storing the old ones? I appreciate deeply any help bacause I would not like in any case to store it spoiled with the old classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also delete the class in svn as well, something like:

```
$ svn rm path/to/class.java
```

You can also remove the file using Eclipse, assuming that you have the svn plugin installed. Make sure that you select the file when you are committing your changeset, otherwise the deletion won't be sent to the server.

Update: Answering the update to the question

```
$ svn mv path/to/OldClass.java path/to/NewClass.java
```

Or, as [Martin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19351115/97627), ensure that your have your subversion plugin in eclipse properly configured, then it will also do the `svn rm` and `svn mv` commands for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Subversion for Eclipse like SubClipse then deleting a file in Eclipse will automatically schedule the file for deletion on next commit.

If you use a Subversion client outside of Eclipse you will have to delete the file using that client and then refresh the project in Eclipse after the file is gone from your working copy.

Comment: @arjacsoh It is still unclear if you are using a plugin or the Subversion commandline. A plugin should handle all Subversion operations for you. In the case of a rename both the old and the new name will often show up in the commit, but make sure that you check what Subversion is doing with the file. The commandline will show an  uppercase letter before the filename - a plugin uses some kind of icon to show what the change is.

Answer (score 0):

SVN needs to know about any changes for all files and folders that are controlled by SVN (i.e. that are put under version control). It is easy to detect file changes, but it is not easy to detect rename and delete operations. If you just delete a file (using your operating system tools), SVN will warn you about a missing file.

For these operations you must use the corresponding [SVN commands](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.html). SVN is best learned, when doing it manually with all those SVN commands (at first).

Using a SVN client makes it a little easier for you. For example, if you use TortoiseSVN, you can right-click a file and choose "SVN delete" for doing both, deleting the file and communicate it to SVN. Same for renaming.

The same is done by using a SVN plugin in Eclipse (Subclipse or Subversive, for example). If you then use Eclipse for deleting or renaming a file, the plugin will also do the operation and communicate it to SVN.

Keep something in mind: When deleting or renaming files (and/or folders) - using SVN commands, of course - you should always do a SVN update prior to SVN commit. Otherwise you might get an error about a revision problem.